# Mule: Illegal character in path at Index

Tags: mule

I am setting my application properties as follows:

```
    consumptionAPI.host = consumptionapi.dev.xxx.com
    consumptionAPI.report = report
    consumptionAPI.month = month
    consumptionAPI.csv = monthly.csv
```

and accessing in my configuration as follows:

```
     <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${consumptionAPI.host}" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>




     <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${consumptionAPI.report}/${consumptionAPI.year}/{yr}/${consumptionAPI.month}/{mth}/${consumptionAPI.csv}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">   

    <http:request-builder>
          <http:uri-param paramName="yr" value="[flowVars.year]"/>
          <http:uri-param paramName="mth" value="[flowVars.month]"/>
       </http:request-builder>  
    </http:request>
```

but when run the flow I get the following error:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://${consumptionAPI.host}:80/${consumptionAPI.report}/${consumptionAPI.year}/[flowVars.year]/${consumptionAPI.month}/[flowVars.month]/${consumptionAPI.csv}

It does not seem to like the first character in the URL but not sure why.

Incidentally if I hardcode the URL it works fine.

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide a value for ${consumptionAPI.year}, then it will leave the $ and curley braces in the path.  That might be a problem depending on your file system.

Or it might collapse it down to "//", in either case, it could cause problems.

Comment: well that I am passing in as a query parameter which I will plug into the constructed URL.

Comment: I just didn't see it in your properties...and your path would start with "report/", which is 7 chars...

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `value="[flowVars.year]"`and it should be `value="#[flowVars.year]"` .
In both the flowVars expression you missed `#` for both month and year flow variables.

So in your url `http://${consumptionAPI.host}:80/${consumptionAPI.report}/${consumptionAPI.year}/[flowVars.year]/${consumptionAPI.month}/[flowVars.month]/${consumptionAPI.csv}` its not able to evaluate the value

and also make sure all the variable you mentioned in your url in `${}` are there defined in your properties file